# wp e-commerce sort by stock

Tags: plugins, sort, e-commerce

I have a site using wp e-commerce plugin and want to sort items by stock. I have been trying for hours without any luck:

- I don't have an option to sort by "SKU" in the administration (as I've read somewhere).
- I have tried using "query_posts" and the result is an infinite loop.
- I have tried accessing wp_query and then setting the query and it doesn't have any effect (maybe it's too late to set the query in the template?

Thanks for any help you could provide.